# Delete all Views out of a LinearLayout (Android)

Tags: android, view, android-linearlayout

So, I've got a `LinearLayout svLv = ...;` where there are some TextViews in(generated dynamically).

All I need is a Method `public void clearEvents(LinearLayout svLv){...}` which **deletes all Views in svLv**.
So after I call the Method there are no Views left in. I have really no Idea how to do this and if this is even possible, because I couldn't find an answer after a bit research on StackOverflow.

I hope you understand what I am looking for.
Thank you for your answers in before!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can try with :

```
svLv.removeAllViews();
svLv.invalidate();
```

Above method will remove all your views.

Comment: +1, and dont forget to call `invalidate` or `invalidateViews` if nothing changed :)

Comment: @BlazeTama yup sorry was forgot to mention it.